# ion_auth : Trigger Send Email when user registers

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, ion-auth

Send certain email when new user register in my website.
How do I do this . where will I attach the my code.
What class and what function..

Answer (score 2):

Look in your ion_auth config file; there is a setting:

```
$config['email_activation']     = FALSE;
```

Set to true, then look at your views to find the activate.tpl.php to customize as needed

Comment: ohh.... got it...Thank you... another question

what if I want to alert my email account (send email to my account).
That a user registered to my website ?

Comment: find the appropriate register method in ion_auth library & add code to cc you